# How to read line by line in php

Tags: php

when i try to insert each line into my oracle database i get an error stating invalid number, but if have only one line in the file it works fine.

```
$file = @fopen('file.text', "r") ;  


// while there is another line to read in the file
while (!feof($file))
{
    // Get the current line that the file is reading
    $currentLine = fgets($file) ;
    $currentLine = explode('        ',$currentLine) ;
    insert($currentLine) ;


}   

fclose($file) ;
```

the lines look like this

```
1     4     100
1     4     101
```

Comment: have you tried to simply echo the queries as you go? Chances are something is not being added to the query they way you think it is.

Comment: Not enough info. Where's your insert function?

Comment: How does your `insert()` function look like?

Comment: @Mel @Alex we don't need `insert()` here as it doesn't influence the issue in any way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `explode()` call is using 9 spaces as a separator, but your file only appears to have 5 spaces between each number. This means your `$currentline` be a single element array containing the original line, and not separate elements with a number in each.

Either change the number of spaces in the explode call, or change to

```
$currentLine = preg_split('/\s+/', $currentLine);
```

which will split on any number of sequential spaces.

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
$currentLine = trim(fgets($file));
```

It's possibly failing on the newline/carriage-return at the end of the line.

If not, where is this insert() function defined?  Build a debug section that echos or writes out the attempted queries so you can really see the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I would double check that there is not a new line at the end of the file. Maybe even double check inside of php that the line read is not blank.

```
$lineCount=0;
// while there is another line to read in the file
while (!feof($file))
{
    $lineCount++;
    // Get the current line that the file is reading
    $currentLine = fgets($file);
    if(trim($currentLine) != ''){
        $currentLine = explode('        ',$currentLine) ;
        insert($currentLine) ;
        echo "Inserted line number $lineCount<br />";
    } else {
        echo "There was a blank line at line number $lineCount.<br />";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$lines = explode("\n", str_replace("\r", "", file_get_contents("file.text")));

foreach ($lines as $line)
{
     insert(explode('        ', $line);
}
```

Comment: There's an easier function for that: `$lines = rtrim(file("file.text"));`

Comment: @jeroen am I missing something or will that not throw an error? file() returns an array, not a string. rtrim() takes a string.

Comment: @user570098 i clarified my answer. if you are still getting an error it's most likely coming from somewhere else.

Comment: Sorry, this is the correct one: `$lines = file("file.text", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);`

Comment: @Jonathan Kuhn Yes, you would need `rtrim` on the array elements, not the array, I already noticed and corrected it (see above).

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
// Read all data in the file
$file_all = file_get_contents('file.text') or die("unable to open file");
// create an array with each index = a line
$file_lines = explode(chr(13),$file_all);
// Insert each line found
foreach ($file_lines as $file_line) { insert($file_line); };
```