# PHP Script for FFMPEG conversion

Tags: php, ffmpeg, flv

Not been programming for long, so go easy.

Basically I'm attempting to write a PHP script that'll be able to automatically convert a folder full of .mp4's for me, and make them .flv's. This will be done for my entire TV collection (which is quite large) to allow for streaming over my local network within browsers.

I've currently got the following code:

```
// Save video files into an array
$vid = glob("../../*.mp4");
// Open text file in write mode
$fp=fopen("test.txt","w+");
// Write contents of array to file
foreach($vid as $key => $value){
fwrite($fp,$value."\n");
}
```

This is taking all of the mp4 files within the folder, and saving their filenames into a text file. The next step I need to take is to read each line, one by one, and perform an FFMPEG command on them until each line has been completed.

Any idea how I can achieve this? I know I'll have to use shell_exec somehow, but I've never used this before, and I'm a little bit stuck as to what to do next.

Thanks for any help

Comment: What you'll need to do is find out how to use ffmpeg on the command line, and then just execute that command with `shell_exec`.  Look at `man ffmpeg` (if you are on a linux system)

Comment: I'm aware of how to use ffmpeg on the command line, and know the command which I will be using to convert the video files. Due to the fact that I need to convert multiple files though, I'll be wanting this to work dynamically through PHP.

I need the script to read each line from a text file, loop a shell_exec script with the ffmpeg command (whilst using PHP variables to change the filename for each conversion), and continue to do so with each line of the text file until the bottom line has been reached.

Hope this clarifies.

Comment: it totally does! but now I fail to see where the problem is... you have detailed the process accurately - where exactly are you having difficulties?

Comment: I want to use PHP to open the text file. Go through each line, using a shell_exec command for ffmpeg on each one, using the contents of each line as the filename to convert.

Comment: yes... you have stated that. what part are you having problems with? are you managing to read the file line by line?

Comment: No. I don't know how to read the file line by line. This is what I haven't done, and need help with:

Read file line by line
Start a loop
Save first line into a variable
Complete FFMEPG command (through shell_exec)
Move onto next line, saving into the variable again

Then continuing that loop until all lines have been read.

Comment: maybe this will help you get stated - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073235/how-to-read-line-by-line-in-php

Comment: Ok thanks, I've now been able to get a loop which goes through each line of the file until I'm at the end of the file. Still having problems though. It doesn't seem to be completing my shell_exec command. I've placed my entire command into a PHP variable name $ffmpeg and then tried to call shell_exec('$ffmpeg'); - this doesn't seem to be converting any of my files though?

Comment: No more help needed. Sorted it :)

Comment: make sure that you have the correct permissions to the folder you are saving the converted files... sounds like you are really close! look out also for any errors that might be getting thrown...

Comment: Hey great! Glad to hear! How about posting your solution as an answer to your question? Someone might face the same problems in the future and you'll be able to help them with your experience!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the ffmpeg command line to convert all the mp4 files in a directory to flv files

```
for i in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -i $i -ar 44100 $i.flv; done
```

Here it is in php

```
// Change directory to the directory of the videos
chdir('../..');

// Run the command
exec('for i in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -i $i -ar 44100 $i.flv; done');
```