# See if previous submission was made using the textbox value in PHP

Tags: php, html

I setup an exam in PHP which takes the user's name and also answers to four questions.

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
<form action="submit.php" method=post>
Your name: <input type=text name=yname value="" size=20 /><br><br>

Question 1:<input type=text name=q1 value="" size=20 /><br>
Question 2:<input type=text name=q2 value="" size=20 /><br>
Question 3:<input type=text name=q3 value="" size=20 /><br>
Question 4:<input type=text name=q4 value="" size=20 /><br>

<input type=submit name=btnsubmit value="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

My PHP Example 'submit.php':

```
<?php
$name = trim(strip_tags(stripslashes($_POST['yname'])));
$q1 = trim(strip_tags(stripslashes($_POST['q1'])));
$q2 = trim(strip_tags(stripslashes($_POST['q2'])));
$q3 = trim(strip_tags(stripslashes($_POST['q3'])));
$q4 = trim(strip_tags(stripslashes($_POST['q4'])));

if ($name <> "" && $q1 <> "" && $q2 <> "" && $q3 <> "" && $q4 <> "") {
    if ($passing > 85) { //value checked in the more comprehensive script
        if ($name == {match from file to see if exam was taken already}) {
            echo "Sorry, but you took the exam already";
        }
        else {
            //....
        }
    }
    else {
        //...
    }
}
?>
```

What I am inquiring is, what is the best way to save the "name" so that it can be used later on if the user were to retake the exam, to compare in the line without the use of a DB:

```
...
if ($name == {match from file to see if exam was taken already}) {
...
```

If possible.

**UPDATE: [RESOLVED]**

```
<?php
global $names;
    $name = trim(strip_tags(stripslashes($_POST['yname'])));
    $q1 = trim(strip_tags(stripslashes($_POST['q1'])));
    $q2 = trim(strip_tags(stripslashes($_POST['q2'])));
    $q3 = trim(strip_tags(stripslashes($_POST['q3'])));
    $q4 = trim(strip_tags(stripslashes($_POST['q4'])));

    $passing = 85;

    $path_to_names_file = 'storename.txt';

    if ($name <> "" && $q1 <> "" && $q2 <> "" && $q3 <> "" && $q4 <> "") {
        if ($passing >= 85) { //value checked in the more comprehensive script
            $names = file($path_to_names_file);
            if(file_exists($path_to_names_file) && in_array($name, $names)) {
                echo "Sorry, but you took the exam already"; //$name has already taken exam
            }
            else { //if name doesn't match, the user is taking it first time. write the name to file for future check
                $fp = fopen($path_to_names_file, 'a');
                fputs($fp, "\n" . $name);
                fclose($fp);
                //file_put_contents($path_to_names_file, "$name\n", FILE_APPEND); //append the file
                echo "Your name is saved";
            }
        }
        else {
            echo "did not pass";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: What do you mean with `so that it can be used later on`? Later when?

Comment: To prevent them from retaking the exam.

Comment: You could use cookies or PHP sessions, but both depend upon the user being on that same computer (and cookies not being deleted). See here [for more information](http://www.lassosoft.com/Tutorial-Understanding-Cookies-and-Sessions). Honestly, it sounds lika a database is your best bet. For a tutorial, see the Login & Registration tutorial [here](http://phpacademy.org)

Comment: So I won't be able to save the value to a text file for later comparison?

Comment: You could also save the data into a hidden field, such as `<input type="hidden" value="John">`, but any page refresh will erase that.

Comment: Honestly, you should invest the time in a MySQL database. There are tons of video tutorials online and it won't take you more than a few hours to master - and then it's yours forever. You needn't even do a Login/Registration system if you don't want -- you can just grab the IP adddress and ask for a user name. This also allows you to store results. Just make sure you learn to code in something like Notepad++ (with its excellent FTP feature) and not in DreamWeaver or  other "system" that separates you from the raw code.

Comment: @gibberish Thanks! am just trying to avoid the DB not because I am not familiar with MYSQL but just trying to avoid the whole mess with SQL injection and our server isn't updated with the version which I am looking to fix and then I will definitely be going into DB rather than file-save

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the data longer than the length of a session, and you are sure the name will be unique enough, and you thoroughly clean the user's input, you can create a file using `file_put_contents()` with the `FILE_APPEND` flag and continuously write new lines to the file. The you can read each line of the file into an array using the `file(0` function and search for the name in the array using `in_array()`.

```
$dir_to_save_file = sys_get_temp_dir();
$file_prefix = '';
$tmp = tmpfile($dir_to_save_file, $file_prefix);
file_put_contents($tmp, "$name\n", FILE_APPEND);
```

then when you want to read the file back

```
$names = file($tmp);
if(in_array($name, $names){
    //$name has already taken exam
}
```

You would obviously create an actual file instead of a temp file and put it whereever you;d like *above* the document root.

**Edit:**

To make a permanent file just pass an absolute path to `file_put_contents`

```
$path = '/path/to/file';
file_put_contents($path, $data, FILE_APPEND);
```

Here is the pastebin with this code: http://pastebin.com/35m45Kt7

Comment: Could be what I am looking for... What is the `$file_prefix` used for? `tmpfile()` needs to be replaced by what to be a permanent file?

Comment: Can I also do this: `$tmp =  fopen($dir_to_save_file, 'r');`

Comment: file_put_contents is easier than the fopen branch of function in my opinion. The documentation says: `this function is identical to calling fopen(), fwrite() and fclose() successively to write data to a file.` which i find helpful.

Comment: Instead of `$path_to_names_file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/../names.txt';` can I use `$path_to_names_file = "storename.txt"; //open file to read`

Comment: You can chmod it to 6XX, the second two numbers can and probably should be 0, so 600. You probbly don't want to file readable by just anyone. If you use `$path_to_names_file = "storename.txt";` then you will have to find out where the file is being saved and make sure you want it there. I prefer using absolute file locations, but it's up to you.

Comment: The following page has the script working to save the name but it doesn't compare the name that exists already and throws the following error: `Warning: in_array() [function.in-array]: Wrong datatype for second argument in /home/web/i/imed.com/htdocs/checksite/save.php on line 14`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32030/discussion-between-ogc-nick-and-sikni8)

Comment: I am in chat... And i will accept your answer, it's almost done from what you have provided.

Comment: I was able to fix it, I updated my question to reflect the changes :)! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can store it on a DB or in another datasource such as a file in the server.

You can take a look at [how to use a text file as an alternative to a Database](http://techmalt.com/?p=333).

You probably don't want something that complex, but you will need to store somewhere the user id and the exams he already took.

You can accomplish this in different ways, creating a file per user with the tests ids, creating a unique file with some separators etc.

Comment: Thanks, but it seems to use MySQL which I am looking to avoid.

Comment: @SiKni8 did you read the page? It is an alternative to ANY database. There's no use of MySQL in there.

Comment: @SiKni8 I quote from the `<h1>` header text: **MyTXT: Use a Text File as Database Alternative in PHP**. *"I called my class “MyTXT” based on “MySQL” because instead of using “Structured Query Language” it simply uses a text file to store data."*

Comment: Yep, saw it. Thanks. Looking into it now.

Comment: @SiKni8 Google `fgetcsv()` also: https://www.google.com/search?q=csv%20php%20fgetcsv%28%29&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=np&source=hp - it could come in handy.

Answer (score 0):

You should store it in a forever cookie.

Forever cookie here means a cookie that lasts for a much long time like 3000 years. In that cookie you can store the name of the user and then always check taking before exam that the user had not given the exam before.

Read about @ [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp) or see its [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php).

You can set a forever cookie or cookie that never expires like this:

```
setcookie(
  "CookieName",
  "CookieValue",
  time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60)
);
```

But then you can take the exam from another PC so for that I recommend you creating a txt file or an unknown format file in which you could store the user's name and then always check the file and then allow or disallow them.

See more about file handling [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file.asp).

You can store the names line by line so that would be easier for you to check.

To check the code line by line see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073235/how-to-read-line-by-line-in-php) on SO.

Comment: The cookie resides in individual PC right? If I am in a different PC than I can retake it and the script won't be able to catch it.

Comment: I can definitely create a unknown format file which stores the name and a `\r\n` and then another name and so forth. In my lookup script I can call the file and how do I read each individual line to compare?

Comment: this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073235/how-to-read-line-by-line-in-php may help you!